# Exclude tabs Rmarkdown based on parameters

Tags: tabs, include, r-markdown, parameterized, chunks

I know I can include exclude r code chunks using parameters in Rmarkdown.
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html

However how can I exclude or include tabs based on the value of a parameter.
Where a tab is indicated as:

```
## Header {.tabset}

### Tab 1
content Tab 1

### Tab 2
content Tab 2

##
```

I'm looking for something like

```
    ## Header {.tabset}

    ### Tab 1
    content Tab 1

    ifelse(param == False) {
    ### Tab 2
    content Tab 2
    }
    ##
```

**Update**

I have some troubles with the answer by StatnMap. Using this code, in the first chunk the HTML after the R chunk is still shown as is the R chunk itself. I could fix this by using a separate `eval = FALSE` for the R chunk, but I would rather restrict myself to a single parameter in a single chunk. Thus, to only set `eval = FALSE` in the asis chunk.

````
## HEADER {.tabset .tabset-pills} 
When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

``` {asis, echo = TRUE, eval = FALSE}
### TEST1
```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
summary(cars)
```
You can also embed plots, for example:
```

### TEST2
```{r, pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your markdown syntax in a `asis` chunk:

````
```{asis, echo=TRUE, eval=param}
### Tab 2
content Tab 2
```
````